# Dozer ,how to use Custom Converter by Id?

Tags: spring, dozer

I am building a Sprint boot Application ,where i make a Request and then i get a Response.
Before i make the request,i need to transform my data.But,the Destination class to transform could be different for the same Source class to transform.
Example :

```
    public Request getTransformedRequest(Request, String typeTransformation) {
        Request transformedRequest= mapper.map(request,Request.class);
        return transformedRequest;
}
```

If i am not using Converters,and i am using just normal Dozer mapping,i can have the following in my mapping.xml;

```
<mapping map-id="Type1">
  <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
  <class-b>ClassB</class-b>   
</mapping> 
<mapping map-id="Type2">
 <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
 <class-b>ClassC</class-b>   
</mapping>
```

And then in my code,for the same Source class ,i can switch using the mapping Id;

```
  ClassB mapper.map(request,Request.class,"Type1"); //Here ClassB extends Request
  ClassC mapper.map(request,Request.class,"Type2"); //Here ClassC extends Request
```

My problem,it s i cant do the same with converters.I want to have different converters for the same source class:

```
  <convertertype="CustomConverterType1" >
    <class-a>
      ClassA
    </class-a>
    <class-b>
      ClassB
    </class-b>
  </converter>
 <converter type="CustomConverterType2" >
    <class-a>
      ClassA
    </class-a>
    <class-b>
      ClassC
    </class-b>
  </converter>
```

So ,in my scenario,i would like to select (like in the mapping id example) ,the converter i wish.
I really appreciate same help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom converters are typically used at the field level to customer the mapping for a specific field pair within the overall mapping for a pair of classes. In this form, Dozer executes the rest of the mapping and calls your converter only for the field with the customer converter.

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
    <class-b>ClassB</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="CustomConverterType1">
        <a>field1</a>
        <b>field1Prime</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
<mapping>
    <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
    <class-b>ClassC</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="CustomConverterType2">
        <a>field1</a>
        <b>field1Prime</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

It is also possible to configure a custom converter at the type level in a way that the converter is responsible for the entire mapping. This must be done in the Dozer configuration, as opposed to the mapping. Note, the converter is responsible for the entire mapping in this case.

```
<configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="CustomConverterType1">
            <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
            <class-b>ClassB</class-b>
        </converter>
        <converter type="CustomConverterType2">
            <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
            <class-b>ClassC</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</configuration>
```

See the Dozer documentation for more information on custom converters.
https://dozermapper.github.io/user-guide.pdf

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ! Yes i know that,but i want to use Converters at Type level,BUT different converters for same pair,choosing at runtime which convertr i want.I can do the same with mapping-id ,but i want to do that with Converters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use Dozer for this at all? Why not just call the right converter based on your condition directly from your code?

Comment: Because i want to use Dozer Capabilities.Thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something. By having a custom converter at the top level type mapping, the converter is doing all of the work, thus bypassing Dozer's functionality. Where in this is Dozer coming into play other than calling Dozer which in turn will just call your custom converter?